# Check if file/image is being loaded from cache?

Tags: asp.net, html

Could anyone recommend any tools to be able to see where external files / images are being loaded from. By this I mean that I'm aware that external JS files / Images are cached on the first load of a page. What I'd like to have is a tool that confirms to me that on subsequent requests these files are in fact being loaded from the users cache rather than downloading the file again.

Apologies, if this has been answered elsewhere, I have tried search but with no luck.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using firefox as the browser, I find that [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a very useful resource for helping with those things, and many others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome), a browser extension (e.g., [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox) or a network sniffer ([Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It shows a list of all requests, their status codes, etc. look for 304 on the image request.